# How to calculate the realized and unrealized PnL of my portfolio

Tags: income, profitability

I am having trouble calculating the Realized profit of my stock portfolio stock.

Here are the transactions:

- I have 50$ to invest
- I buy 2 Stocks A at 10$ each
- I later buy 2 Stocks A  at 15$ each, I now have 0€ balance.
- I sell 3 Stocks A at 20$ each. In the end there is 1 stock worth 20$ and a 60$ balance.

In the end we have a total is 80$, meaning a 30$ profit. However I can't understand what amount of this is realized and what is unrealized profit.

As I have 60$ balance and I had an initial 50$ balance, the realized profit should be 10$.
However if this were true, the remainder 20$ should be unrealized profit which is can't be right as
average price for which I bought the stock was  `(2 * 10$+2 * 15$)/5 =` 12.5$. From 12.5$->20$ would mean a 7.5$ unrealized profit.
  **7.5$** is different from **20$** so something is not correct

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default sold shares will go FIFO (first-in, first-out).

Of the 3 shares you sold at $20, 2 had a basis of $10 and one at $15, so you realized gains of $10, $10, and $5. And you have left 1 share with $15 basis and $5 unrealized gain.

If you directed your broker to sell specific shares then you'd have a different calculation.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that the FIFO mechanism was the norm. Makes sense!